# How to get fmt.Printf or fmt.Prinln line numbers shown in golang?

Tags: go

Excuseme for my English.

I need to show the line number of the `fmt.Println` in un go application, because I have many `fmt.Prinf` and `fmt.Println` in many go files. example

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hello golang")
}
```

I would like the output to show like this.

```
main.go [line 6] hello golang
```

**i.e, the name of the file, the line number of the fmt.Printf and the message.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to get line numbers in the output is to use the [standard log package](https://godoc.org/log) with [file name output enabled](https://godoc.org/log#Llongfile).

Add this function to your program to enable file name output. The function is called automatically when the application starts.

```
func init() {
    log.SetFlags(log.Flags() | log.Llongfile)
}
```

Use the [log.Printf](https://godoc.org/log#Printf) and other functions in the log package to print messages:

```
func main() {
    log.Printf("hello golang")
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/F3Xn2JHYexP)

Use [LshortFile](https://godoc.org/log#Lshortfile) instead of [LlongFile](https://godoc.org/log#Llongfile) to get shorter file name output.

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zJE-sbjZVQn)

If neither of these formats meet your needs, then copy the [code from the log package](https://golang.org/src/log/log.go) and adjust as needed.

Comment: Thanks so much bruth